# How does python generate random number from normal distribution?

Tags: python, random, sampling, normal-distribution

I know that `random.normal()` will give me a random number from normal distribution. But how does it actually generate it? I understand that `random.random()` is either generated by a seed or using system randomness. Is `random.normal()` also generated similarly? or is it by **[rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling)** technique?

Comment: You probably have a wrong mental model of how random number generation, if you're under the impression that "by a seed or using system randomness" and "by rejection sampling" are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Did you look at the source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py#L393

Comment: Also, there is no `random.normal`. You may be mixing up `random` and `numpy.random`.

Answer (score 4):

The [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py#L393) says that `random.normalvariate()` is generated as follows:

```
# Uses Kinderman and Monahan method. Reference: Kinderman,
# A.J. and Monahan, J.F., "Computer generation of random
# variables using the ratio of uniform deviates", ACM Trans
# Math Software, 3, (1977), pp257-260.

random = self.random
while 1:
    u1 = random()
    u2 = 1.0 - random()
    z = NV_MAGICCONST*(u1-0.5)/u2
    zz = z*z/4.0
    if zz <= -_log(u2):
        break
return mu + z*sigma
```

The original paper is available [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/355744.355750), though it takes some effort to follow it.

This is, clearly, a form of rejection sampling.

If you set a seed, it specifies the sequence of random numbers generated by `random.random()` or `random.normalvariate()`. If you don't set a seed, then randomness is drawn from the machine. Which is to say, you *cannot* compare the operation of `random.normalvariate` and seeding: they are two different operations, one of which supports the other.

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.normalvariate), the random normal distribution is generated upon the random() function, which gives a uniform float in [0, 1) which as the documentation says "uses the **Mersenne Twiste**r as the core generator. It produces 53-bit precision floats and has a period of 2**19937-1"

I have no idea what Mersenne Twister is, but hopefully the information helps.